# Variable assignment in jQuery

Tags: jquery

New to jQuery and having some trouble understanding some of the syntax. What is going on in this code snippet?

```
var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    method = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};
```

Is it defining 4 variable or a data structure. This code is inside a jQuery block of code executed when a form is submitted. `$(this)` is the form being submitted. I'm not even sure where to start Googling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code is defining 4 separate variables, unrelated to any common data structure.  It's equivalent to this:

```
var that = $(this);
var url = that.attr('action');
var method = that.attr('method');
var data = {};
```

- `that` is defined as a jQuery reference to whatever `this` is in the context in which this code runs (likely a `form` element in this case).
- `url` is a string, the value of the `action` attribute on the DOM element.
- `method` is a string, the value of the `method` attribute on the `DOM` element.
- `data` is an empty object.

Note that this is more "JavaScript" syntax than "jQuery" syntax.  jQuery is only involved here in how the first three variables get their values.  `$()` is a jQuery function that returns a jQuery object, but the actual syntax of calling it is like any other JavaScript.  And `.attr()` is a function on a jQuery object.

Comment: Ok, so it's just a short hand. That was my guess. Thanks for all the info.